# HTML5: Drawing Letter with SVG Path

Tags: html, svg, draw

I need to create some alphabets (**AEGLNRUTSZ**) using `svg path`.

**Q.** Is there any tool or technique available? I spent all day, playing with code but it seems very complex and don't make any sense. :(

Here's the **example snippet**, it draws letter **D**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M28.2371517,0.75 C32.7510836,1.7 36.0111455,3.55 39.371517,7.05 C42.4309598,10.25 44.3368421,13.9 45.1393189,18 C45.7913313,21.45 45.7913313,58.55 45.1393189,62.05 C43.4340557,71.15 35.6600619,78.25 26.0303406,79.5 C24.0241486,79.75 17.3034056,80 11.1845201,80 L-7.10542736e-15,80 L-7.10542736e-15,1.42108547e-14 L12.4383901,1.42108547e-14 C21.2656347,1.42108547e-14 25.7795666,0.2 28.2371517,0.75 Z M14.5448916,40 L14.5448916,65.6 L19.7108359,65.4 C24.174613,65.25 25.1275542,65.05 27.1337461,63.9 C31.0458204,61.6 31.0959752,61.45 31.0959752,39.7 C31.0959752,18.5 31.0959752,18.5 27.4346749,16.1 C25.6291022,14.9 24.8767802,14.75 19.9616099,14.55 L14.5448916,14.4 L14.5448916,40 Z" fill="
```

Comment: you can use Illustrator to convert text to outlines http://www.graphic-design-employment.com/adobe-illustrator-how-to-convert.html

Comment: Any vector editor that supports SVG files, should do the job.  Not just Illustrator.